# How to make WTForms read from the datastore?

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore, python-2.7, wtforms

I'm trying to enable a use case "add city" where I got model definitions for region and city where a city belongs to a region:

```
class Region(db.Model):
  name = db.StringProperty()
  vieworder = db.IntegerProperty()
  image = db.BlobProperty()

class City(db.Model):
  region = db.ReferenceProperty()
  name = db.StringProperty()
  image = db.BlobProperty()
  vieworder = db.IntegerProperty()
  areacode = db.IntegerProperty()
```

I then add regions manually and have made a form to add the cities:

```
class AddCityForm(Form):

    my_choices = [
        ('0', _('All regions')),
        ('1', _('Delhi')),
    ]
    region = SelectField(choices=my_choices)
    name = TextField(_('Name'))

class AddCityHandler(BaseRequestHandler):

    def get(self):
        logging.info('i baserequesthandler')
        self.render('addcity.html', {'form': AddCityForm()})
```

Now I want the choices to read from the data layer and be all the regions like `Region.all()` and the IDs the IDs of the entities so that I can populate a city with the key of the region as a reference which region it belongs to. Can you tell me how I can make WTForms populate the options from the datastore with my regions?

THank you

### Update

In GAE, the following code works to make option read from datastore

```
class RegionField(SelectField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegionField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.choices = []
        for region in Region.all().fetch(99999):
        self.choices.append([region.key().id(), region.name])

class AddCityForm(Form):
    region = RegionField()
    name = TextField(_('Name'))
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can subclass a SelectField:

```
class RegionField(SelectField):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(RegionField, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        # a sample sqlalchemy query that returns a list of tuples (id, name)
        self.choices = models.Session.query(models.Region.id, models.Region.name).order_by(models.Region.name).all()

class AddCityForm(Form):
    region = RegionField()
    name = TextField(_('Name'))
```

Note that depending on how your persistence layer operates you may need to also implement `populate_obj(self, obj, name)` in order to coerce submitted data into something your ORM would understand (this is more likely to be necessary with a SelectMultipleField).

Comment: are you sure that this way the instance won't cache the fields value and maybe not load the newest choices?

Comment: @aschmid00: there's some magic at work there. When you do `class MyForm(Form): myfield = MyField()`, `MyForm.myfield` is assigned an instance of an `UnboundField`. Actual field construction happens when you do `form = MyForm()`, and that's something you do in your view handler once per request (unless you do your own caching).

Comment: Thank you for the answer and comments. I found a way with your help that worked and I posted it to the original question as an update.